# My jQuery .hover's are working fine, but I can't get .click to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, click

My aim is to make this text change to `opacity: 0` on click. However, I can't get it to respond.

HTML

```
<div class="click-contact">
    <h2 class="insignia-inner-text">contact</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery(".click-contact").click(function() {
            jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "0"});
    }); 
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy787/

I'm using wordpress so I have to run noConflict, but it's been working fine for all of my .hover functions.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is working fine in the fiddle if you add an js library...See this http://jsfiddle.net/Gy787/3/

Comment: you haven't selected the jquery framework in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gy787/2/

Comment: Your code works fine, you just hadn't included jQuery in the dropdown in the top left of jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy787/1/

Comment: I see. Why can I not get it to work on my wordpress site then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included `jQuery` in fiddle. It is working fine.

Comment: The solution was floating my divs higher than other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your contact are not loading dynamically in that case use :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("div").on('click','.click-contact', function() {
            jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "0"});
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Curiously that still does nothing for me.